# How do you create an instance of RsaSecurityKey from a SSL key file

Tags: c#, rsa, .net-core

I have a RSA private key in the format as stated in [RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-10) and a library I'm using requires an instance of `SecurityKey` none of the constructor's seem to accept strings in this format, nor any of the accepted arguments for it's constructor seem to accept this format.

Comment: Any code, please?

Comment: `SecurityKey` isn't a .NET framework type. So maybe you should also say what library you're trying to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Found a Library that handles PEM Keys in .Net](https://github.com/huysentruitw/pem-utils), If you include both DerConverter and PemUtils you can simply read the file:

```
RsaSecurityKey key;
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
using (var reader = new PemReader(stream))
{
    key = new RsaSecurityKey(reader.ReadRsaKey());
    // ...
}
```